# Double-layered optimization to find optimal regularization parameter lambda for Ridge/LASSO

Tags: optimization, lasso, ridge-regression, convex

I have an overdetermined system of equations problem where `n >> m` and the OLS almost always finds an approximation instead of an exact solution. I already reduce the problem space from A to a lot smaller matrix A' using an algorithm based on domain knowledge but it is still not enough.

The idea is to employ a regularized solver such as LASSO or Ridge to try to find an exact solution to the reduced system of equations. However, I need to find the optimal $\lambda$ that achieves an exact or the closest to the exact solution.

For example I can use [Ridge regression because it has a closed form solution](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4780/2018fa/lectures/lecturenote08.html). The closed form solution is:

1. $x=(AA^T + \lambda I)^{-1}Ab^T$

given that I'd like to find an exact solution for:

2. $Ax=b$

How can I cast this problem in terms of a convex optimization problem? I would need the objective function and the derivative of it w.r.t. $\lambda$ but this leads me to the ridge problem setting, maybe I am a bit confused now :)

Comment: Hi, can you confirm that $n$ is the number of observations and $m$ is the number of variables? I.e., that $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$?

Comment: Yes indeed n is the number of observations and m the number of columns i.e. A nxm very overdetermined.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Then what do you mean by "exact solution"? And what makes you think regularization can help with this?